# K-means error in foreign function call

Tags: rstudio, cluster-analysis

I am trying to do the clustering on a set of data using the easy:

```
fit <- kmeans(my data, 2)
```

The problem is, when I run it, I get:

> Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
>   In addition: Warning message: In kmeans(my data, 2) : NAs introduced 
>   by coercion

Even though I checked whether I had only numbers in the data set.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, can you do `str(my data)`? Second, don't use a space in the name. 
Maybe you have numeric **id** columns.

Please see [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203592/basic-clustering-with-r) and [link 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138591/plotting-k-means-clustering-with-mixed-numerical-categorical-data).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  

How can I check how well the number of clusters is chosen and plot it? My data is one variable.

Comment: @CezaryŁastowski, are you want to cluster a 1-dimensional variable? Here's a 2-dimensional example  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html